# How to return values for multiple dates in the same query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables:

**@Payments**

[image]

**@ControlNo**

[image]

Each date represents `TotalIncurred` amount as of that date.

So if I want to get the last one (As Of today) , I'll simply use self join with `MAX(PaymentID)`

```
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ClaimID, MAX(PaymentID) AS MaxPaymentID 
     FROM @Payments mp 
     GROUP BY ClaimID) a ON a.ClaimID = p.ClaimID AND a.MaxPaymentID = p.PaymentID
```

[image]

But how would I also bring  `TotalIncurred` as of `2019-05-22`, and let's say as of `'2019-05-08'`. I dont need to pivot it for all dates, just for the last week, last month, last quarter etc.

The result should look like picture below on a right:

[image]

Would that be possible to do that in the same query?

Code sample:

```
DECLARE @Payments TABLE 
                  (  
                      ClaimID INT, 
                      PaymentID INT,  
                      TotalIncurred MONEY, 
                      dateCreated DATE
                  )

INSERT INTO @Payments 
VALUES (123, 1131215, 250, '2019-03-01'),
       (123, 1132307, 130, '2019-05-18'),
       (123, 1140297, 50, '2019-05-22'),
       (123, 1155063, 80, '2019-06-30')

DECLARE @ControlNo TABLE (ClaimID int, ControlNo int)

INSERT INTO @ControlNo 
VALUES (123, 54321)

--SELECT * FROM @Payments
--SELECT * FROM @ControlNo

SELECT 
    c.ControlNo,
    SUM(TotalIncurred) AS TotalIncurred
FROM 
    @Payments p 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ClaimID, MAX(PaymentID) AS MaxPaymentID 
     FROM @Payments mp 
     GROUP BY ClaimID) a ON a.ClaimID = p.ClaimID AND a.MaxPaymentID = p.PaymentID
INNER JOIN 
    @ControlNo c ON c.ClaimID = p.ClaimID
GROUP BY 
    c.ControlNo

-- For the last week I'd use DateCreated <= GETDATE() -7
SELECT 
    c.ControlNo,
    SUM(TotalIncurred) AS TotalIncurred
FROM 
    @Payments p 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ClaimID, MAX(PaymentID) AS MaxPaymentID 
     FROM @Payments mp 
     WHERE DateCreated < = GETDATE() - 7  
     GROUP BY ClaimID) a ON a.ClaimID = p.ClaimID AND a.MaxPaymentID = p.PaymentID
INNER JOIN 
    @ControlNo c ON c.ClaimID = p.ClaimID
GROUP BY 
    c.ControlNo
```

Comment: How do you define "just some of them?"

Comment: I would need like Last week, Last month,  last quarter.
So for last week I'd say: `WHERE DateCreated <= GETDATE() -7`

Comment: `For the last week I'd use DateCreated <= GETDATE() -7` . Shouldn't that be `>=`